# What are some interesting uses for/motivations of projective spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

I have trouble motivating myself to think about real projective spaces, for instance. Are there any cool results about them? Are there any motivating examples?

Comment: Well, you can walk forward along one on a certain path and end up back where you started facing the opposite direction. *Motivated now?*

Comment: This seems a bit too opinion based and broad. Could you try and improve it? For example, what qualifies as a "cool" result? What motivates you to study something?

Comment: from a post-Kleinian point of view, all geometry is projective geometry. so that's motivation.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent motivation is artistic/biologic. When an artist try to represent the reality on a painting, he must project it on a plane. The geometry needed to make the painting as close as possible to the reality is  the projective geometry. To represent tiles keeping the proportions, one need to use the cross-ratio. Apparently this is a mathematician (Luca Pacioli) who  learned this to A Durer.

More recently this geometry is now used in the shape recognition problem. From 2 or 3 picture, how can a computer re-build the three dimensional object.(see here for a nice introduction http://robotics.stanford.edu/~birch/projective/projective.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Since you included [differential-geometry](/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) as one of the tags, one could mention a pretty result called Pu's theorem about the real projective plane $RP^2$ with an arbitrary Riemannian metric.  Consider the least length $L$ of a noncontractible loop in $RP^2$.  Let $A$ be the total area of the metric on $RP^2$.  Then these two invariants are related by a kind of "reverse isoperimetric inequality", namely $L^2 \leq \frac{\pi}{2}A$. This inequality is sharp, in the sense that the boundary case of equality is attained by a "round" metric, i.e., a metric of constant Gaussian curvature.